# CollapsingToolbarLayout makes RecyclerView NOT scrollable until bottom after fragment view recreation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, material-components

In 1st fragment I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with pinned Toolbar. For CollapsingToolbarLayout I have set `layout_scrollFlags` to be `"scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` since I wanted Toolbar to stay pinned.

When I scroll down so that CollapsingToolbarLayout gets collapsed, then click on any item inside RecyclerView to navigate to next screen and then come back to 1st screen after clicking on back button **I can't see nor scroll to last item**. I can scroll to the very bottom if I first scroll to top and make CollapsingToolbarLayout expanded. It looks like CollapsingToolbarLayout eats from bottom of RecyclerView a vertical space equal to height of Toolbar.

But if I remove `exitUntilCollapsed` from `layout_scrollFlags` and use others problem is gone but toolbar gets collapsed.

I have tried material library version 1.1.0 and 1.2.0 and latest 1.3.0-alpha02. The problem looks to be present on all of these versions.

I wonder if there is a problem in my code or is it a bug in library?

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorTransparent"
    app:titleEnabled="false"
    app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_fragment_tv_first_row"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="First row"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/first_fragment_tv_second_row"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_goneMarginBottom="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_fragment_tv_second_row"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFeatureSettings="smcp,c2sc"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Second row"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_fragment_tv_first_row" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="First Fragment"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1576) on [material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) Github page.

Now issue is closed and it is said to be fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/a21a30026a33fc20cf7ad699d32d1298b84096c6). I will update my answer when I will know more about which version of the library contains that fix.